# Android Fragment Scroll view on Landscape view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am relatively new to android development and is still learning thru. I need help on my fragments. I have a fragment page that looks ok on a portrait mode but messed up on landscape as seen on this screenshot:

[image: messed up landscape portrait]

I have already tried scrollview but it shuts down my app. Right now, here's my a part of my xml code:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardTop"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What do I need to do to fix this or should i say make it responsive according to screen orientation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by creating different XML layouts for different orientations. The following is from Google Developer docs:

To specify configuration-specific alternatives for a set of resources:

- Create a new directory in res/ named in the form `<resources_name>-<config_qualifier>`.
- `<resources_name>` is the directory name of the corresponding default resources
- `<qualifier>` is a name that specifies an individual configuration for which these resources are to be used.

In your case, you have to create a folder in res/ named `layout-land` and placing the alternate XML layout with the same name as the XML layout you are currently using.

If you don't want your activity to rotate, you can set the orientation of your activity as `portrait` in the Manifest file.

**EDIT:** Here is a sample of how to force `portrait` orientation.

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

The manifest will already have the `activity` tag for your activity. Just add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to it.

Comment: Can you walk me thru the codes on this one? "If you don't want your activity to rotate, you can set the orientation of your activity as portrait in the Manifest file."

Comment: I was able to force the portrait view. But I realized it doesn't do justice to my users if I have it on portrait all the time. if I opt for this option: "In your case, you have to create a folder in res/ named layout-land and placing the alternate XML layout with the same name as the XML layout you are currently using." ---  does this mean I have to have 2 different xml fragments? one for portrait and one for landscape? What if I only want to just have a scroll option to see contents when in landscape and as is if in portrait?

Comment: You won't have two different fragments. Just different layouts. The device will choose the layout based on the orientation. Go through https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources for more info.

Comment: I have created another layout, how would this be directed on my activity?

Comment: I will be applied on changing the orientation of the device